# Postgres: Group by hour and append the missing hours to the result with 0 counts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query, which returns the values correctly.

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', created_at)                                     as date,
       CAST(COUNT(case when subscription = true then id end) AS INTEGER)  as subscriptions,
       CAST(COUNT(case when subscription = false then id end) AS INTEGER) as unsubscriptions
FROM requests
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Output:

| date | subscriptions | unsubscriptions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-14 23:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-14 20:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 10 | 1 |
| 2021-01-14 18:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 0 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**The problem is that i need the missing hours of the day even if there are not any entries in the table, with 0 count.**

Expected output:

| date | subscriptions | unsubscriptions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-14 23:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-14 22:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-14 21:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-14 20:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 10 | 1 |
| 2021-01-14 19:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-14 18:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 0 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Table Structure:

| id | subscription | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| int | bool | timestamp |

Comment: can you post the table you're working with as well?

Comment: Can you add some data to it? I'm just trying to see what you have to figure out what you got that's not working. Also, `count` returns bigint so I'm not sure why you need the `cast` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a timeseries for the timeseries you want to report and `LEFT JOIN` your table with it. You can use `generate_series` to create that.

```
--Sample table
WITH YOUR_TABLE AS (
  SELECT NOW() AS created_at, TRUE AS subscription
  UNION SELECT NOW() - interval '3 hour', FALSE
  UNION SELECT NOW() - interval '5 hour', TRUE
  UNION SELECT NOW() - interval '5 hour', FALSE
  UNION SELECT NOW() - interval '8 hour', FALSE
),
--Generate time series based on min and max created_at
TIME_SERIES AS (
  SELECT GENERATE_SERIES AS hour
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES
        ( (SELECT MIN(date_trunc('hour', created_at)) FROM YOUR_TABLE)
        , (SELECT MAX(date_trunc('hour', created_at)) FROM YOUR_TABLE)
        , '1 hour'::interval))

--Left join your table to the generated time series  
SELECT 
   TIME_SERIES.hour, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN subscription = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as subscriptions,
   SUM(CASE WHEN subscription = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unsubscriptions
FROM TIME_SERIES
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE
ON TIME_SERIES.hour = date_trunc('hour', created_at) 
GROUP BY TIME_SERIES.hour
ORDER BY TIME_SERIES.hour
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XkqXSxk8)

Comment: It actually works nice. My only issue is the interval, since i need the generated series from the date which is equal to the first row's timestamp of the requests table.

Comment: @Makis You can do this by using the min and max timestamp from your table. I edited the query in the answer so it does that.

Comment: Correct! i did it as well, marked as correct!